# How to sign up to a website with python 3?

Tags: forms, python-3.x, web, sign

I would like to build a simple automated signer up for a website of mine.

I tried with this:

```
import requests

url = "http://pountex.altervista.org/registrati/"

payload = { "user": "a",
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "passw1": "a",
        "passw2": "a" } 

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print (r.text)
```

But nothing happends. The comment doesn't being created.

This is the html part of the comments form:

```
<input class="text-input default_field_username" name="username" maxlength="70" id="username" value="" type="text">
<input class="text-input default_field_email" name="email" maxlength="70" id="email" value="" type="email">
<input class="text-input" name="passw1" maxlength="70" id="passw1" value="" autocomplete="off" type="password">
<input class="text-input" name="passw2" maxlength="70" id="passw2" value="" autocomplete="off" type="password">
<input name="register" id="register" class="submit button" value="Registrati " type="submit">
```

Comment: This is for educational purposes, right?

Comment: please help me! I tried everything! urllib, selenium, requests, sockets... can you show me the way

Comment: Interesting question. These links might provide some help: [submitting a form using `requests`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094616/using-python-to-submit-a-web-form-with-liburl-or-requests) and [submitting a form with `urllib`](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/). You are using `POST`, but it seems you have the `write` to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

@nander-speerstra thanks for your links, but the real problems was the http request. I've always sended:

```
payload = { "user": "a",
            "email": "a@a.com",
            "passw1": "a",
            "passw2": "a" }
```

But after an analysis of http post request, i realized the there were these options:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

a@a.com
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="passw1"

a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="passw2"

a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="register"

Registrati 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

register
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_name"

unspecified
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="register_nonce_field"

5d5162e9e1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wp_http_referer"

/registrati/
```

So the final script is:

```
import requests

url = "http://pountex.altervista.org/registrati/"

payload = { "username":"a",
            "email":"a@a.com",
            "passw1":"a",
            "passw2":"a",
            "register":"Registrati ",
            "action":"register",
            "form_name":"unspecified",
            "register_nonce_field":"59cf20fe78",
            "_wp_http_referer":"/registrati/?doing_wp_cron=1470266089.5451300144195556640625"
            }

r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```